# Python: Printing data only when number enters or leaves interval

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem

Currently I'm making a script that, given a set of celestial coordinates, will tell you on the next days when that point will be visible for a specific telescope. The criteria is simple, in the Horizontal Coordinate system, altitude of the object must be between 30 and 65 degrees(Variable "crit" here represents that, but in radians).
So I have a set of parameters for the telescope called "Ant" and then, using Pyephem:

```
#imported ephem as ep
obj= ep.FixedBody()
obj._ra= E.ra
obj._dec= E.dec
obj._epoch = E.epoch
Ant.date = ep.now()
for d in range(days):
    for i in range(24):
        for j in range (60):
            Ant.date += ep.minute       
            obj.compute(Ant)
            crit= float(obj.alt)
            if crit>=0.523599 and crit <=1.13446:
                print "Visible at %s" %Ant.date
```

Which results in printing a lot of "Visible at 2016/7/11 19:41:21", 1 for every minute.
I Just want it to print something like "Enters visibility at 2016/7/11 19:41:21, leaves at 2016/7/11 23:41:00", for example.
Any Ideas will be appreciated.

Disclaimer: Sorry, not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether it is already in range. So, for instance, at the beginning you'd initialize it:

```
is_visible = False
```

and your if statement might look like:

```
if crit>=0.523599 and crit <=1.13446:
    if not is_visible:
        print "Visible at %s" %Ant.date
        is_visible = True
else:
    if is_visible:
        print "No longer visible at %s" % Ant.date
        is_visible = False
```

Comment: This is almost there, Now I just need to print when the point leaves the range.

Comment: Edited to add that.

Comment: Working perfectly, Thanks a lot